# Keep stopwatch ticking until user leaves the web page

Tags: c#-4.0

I’m trying to record the amount of time a user spends on page

I’m working with the following code;

```
 var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
       watch.Start();

        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.Elapsed.Seconds;
```

Comment: What page it is? Window or Web based ?

Comment: it's a web page

Comment: Every solution resulting to this, may or may not be 100% everytime. Better  if u use client side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341774/keep-track-of-how-much-time-is-spent-showing-certain-elements-on-the-page