# Measure amount of time on div

Tags: javascript

I have a feed that contains posts. It looks something like this:

```
<div class="feed">
<div class="post">
  ...content...
</div>
<div class="post">
  ...content...
</div>
<div class="post">
  ...content...
</div>
</div>
```

If a user scrolls to a post and is there for 2 seconds (Most of the post is shown in the user's window), then we can call that a view. Is there a way in JavaScript to detect an event like this and label it as a view?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341774/keep-track-of-how-much-time-is-spent-showing-certain-elements-on-the-page

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7svZr/2/

Comment: Yep use a timeout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<div id="divs">
    <div>First</div>
    <div class="selected">Second</div>
    <div>Third</div>
    <div>Fourth</div>
</div>

<p id="output"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var divs = $('#divs > div'),
    output = $('#output'),
    tarr = [0, 0, 0, 0],
    delay = 100;

divs.click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

setInterval(function() {
    var idx = divs.filter('.selected').index();
    tarr[idx] = tarr[idx] + delay;
    output.text('Times (in ms): ' + tarr);
}, delay);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7svZr/2/

I keep the times in milliseconds because integers are cleaner and safer (`0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`). Note that you can adjust the "precision" (the delay of the interval function) by setting the `delay` variable.

**This should do the trick:**

```
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
    {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }
```

**Simple Utility Function**
    This will allow you to call a utility function that accepts the element you're looking for and if you want the element to be fully in view or partially.

```
    function Utils() {

    }

    Utils.prototype = {
        constructor: Utils,
        isElementInView: function (element, fullyInView) {
            var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
            var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
            var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();

            if (fullyInView === true) {
                return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
            } else {
                return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
            }
        }
    };
```

**Usage**

```
    var Utils = new Utils();
    var isElementInView = Utils.isElementInView($('#flyout-left-container'), false);

    if (isElementInView) {
        console.log('in view');
    } else {
        console.log('out of view');
    }
```

**Cutom code I made**

```
function Utils() {

}

Utils.prototype = {
  constructor: Utils,
  isElementInView: function (element, fullyInView) {
    var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
    var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();

    if (fullyInView === true) {
      return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
    } else {
      return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
    }
  }
};

var Utils = new Utils();

var divs = $('#divs > div'),
    output = $('#output'),
    tarr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    delay = 100;

setInterval(function() {
  var idx = 0;
  $(divs).each(function(){
    if(Utils.isElementInView(this, false)) {
      tarr[idx] = tarr[idx] + delay;
      output.text('Times (in ms): ' + tarr);
    }
    idx++;
  });
}, delay);
```

Example Demo Fiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/8ndzxchf/1/

Comment: You'll have to select for it to calculate time. I'm talking about a way of knowing the div is in the viewport view and if it's been like 2 seconds for example, it counts that as a view

Comment: Ahh sorry about that here you go Example Demo Fiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/8ndzxchf/1/  just scroll the scrollbar you will see the times will stop going up for not visible div's

Comment: Thank you for your answer...just a quick question, would this affect a site's performance any if this were added to always check if a div is in the viewport?

Comment: Probably not the code in isElementInView will probably run instantly for any amount of Div's.. it's just requesting information about div's and doing simple math to check if they are in the view area but ya.. the timer is ran every 100 milliseconds which could eat some CPU to continuously keep running non-stop that's about it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element.

Here is a complete tutorial on [Timing element visibility with the Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API/Timing_element_visibility). It demonstrates how to use the Intersection Observer API to track how much time each ad is visible to the user. When an ad exceeds one minute of visible time, it will be replaced with a new one. It is very similar to your use case.